# Is there a word for a secret/truth hidden in plain sight?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for a secret/truth hidden in plain sight? Like something that should be obvious to someone who is highly educated or intelligent, but is hidden from ordinary people, because they can't see it even if it's right there in front of them (figuratively speaking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sherlock Holmes was able to deduce things that were obvious to him because of his intellect and deduction, but which other people were not able to see.

A truth that is hidden from normal perception could be considered [**camouflaged**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/camouflage):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **camouflage** noun
>   **2 a** : concealment by means of disguise
>         // The rabbit's white fur acts as *camouflage* in the snow.
>   **2 b** : behavior or artifice designed to deceive or hide
>         // hiding behind a *camouflage* of righteous indignation
>
> **camouflage** verb
>   **camouflaged; camouflaging**
>   transitive verb
>   : to conceal or disguise by camouflage
>   // The makeup *camouflages* blemishes.
>   intransitive verb
>   : to practice camouflage

In the sense of the question:

> The truth was *camouflaged* behind ordinary details that only the very perceptive could see through.